# Django model id being overwritten by id of GenericForeignKey

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I am trying create a new database entry using a custom Django model I created. However, when I try to create the model and save it, the id does not increment. Instead, the previous database entry is overwritten whose id == 1. I have tried setting *force_insert=True* inside the save() function, but it results in a runtime error where the primary key already exists. I don't set any primary values in the creation of the object, so I'm not sure why the id is not being incremented. I am running the test code in the manage.py shell. All the models have been migrated properly.

The model:

```
class RoadWayData(models.Model):
    blocked_lanes = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    direction = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    eto = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    incident_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    incident_object = GenericForeignKey('incident_type', 'id')
    injuries = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    postmile = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    queue = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="NONE: Freeflow Conditions")
    route = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    update = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    maintenance = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tow = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    weather = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    vehicles_involved = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

The test code:

```
from incident.models import *
import datetime

x = IncidentIndex.objects.get(id=1)
y = CHPIncident.objects.get(id=x.incident_object.id)

print("ID already exists in DB: {}".format(RoadWayData.objects.get(id=1).id))

z = RoadWayData(
        blocked_lanes=0,
        city="testCity",
        county="testCounty",
        direction="NB",
        eto="Unknown",
        highway_accident=True,
        incident_object=y,
        injuries=0,
        postmile="New Postmile",
        route="new Route",
        update = 2,
        maintenance= "Not Requested",
        tow="Not Requested",
        weather="Clear Skies",
        vehicles_involved=0,
    )

z.save()
print("New Data Object ID: {}".format(z.id))
```

Shell Output:

```
ID already exists in DB: 1
New Data Object ID: 1
```

**Edit #1:**
I am using a mySQL database and have not overridden the save() function. The mySQL console shows only one entry in the table(the model that was most recently saved).

**Edit #2**
I commented out the RoadWayData model and migrated the changes to wipe the table. Afterwards, I un-commented the model and migrated the changes to add it back to the database. The issue still persists.

**Edit #3**
I was able to manually insert a new entry into the table using the mySQL console.   The ID incremented correctly. Perhaps it is a Django bug?

**Edit #4**
I've pinpointed the source of the problem. The problem stems from the *contenttypes* library. More specifically, the *GenericForeignKey*. For some reason when an the content object is assigned, the model inherits the content object's id.

Code with problem isolated:

```
x = IncidentIndex.objects.get(id=1)
y = CHPIncident.objects.get(id=x.incident_object.id)
r = RoadWayData( 
    ... 
    incident_object = None,  # Do not assign the generic foreign key
    ...
)

r.save()
print(r) # Shows <RoadWayData object> with CORRECT id
r.incident_object = y # Assign the general object
print(r) # Shows <RoadWayData object> with the id of y. INCORRECT
```

The easiest fix would be to create a variable to keep track of the Model's id BEFORE assigning the content_object (*incident_object* in my case).

**FIX:**

```
... initialization from code above ...

r.save()
r_id = r.id # SAVE THE CORRECT ID BEFORE ASSIGNING GENERIC FOREIGN KEY

r.incident_object = y # ASSIGN THE GENERIC FOREIGN OBJECT

r.id = r_id # OVERWRITE THE ID WITH THE CORRECT OLD ID
r.save()
```

Comment: Did you override the save() method? Also what DB are you using?

Comment: very weird. check your database table using an SQL console. If needed migrate back to delete the table and migrate forward again to re-create it.

Comment: @marke I have not overriden the save() method. I am using a mySQL.

Comment: I know it shouldn't matter but have you tried using the `RoadWayData.objects.create(...` notation?

Comment: Did you create the table using a migration or was it already in the database? What does the migration look like? And if you open a db shell, what does `DESCRIBE yourapp_roadwaydata;` output?

Comment: @gdef_ I have tried using the create() notation. It results in the same error as save(force_insert=True). It tries to use id=1 and a primary key error occurs because a previous entry with id=1 exists.

Comment: @Alasdair I created the table using a migration. I'm not sure what you mean by, "what does the migration look like?" I just added the model to the models.py file in my app directory then ran the makemigrations and migrate commands. Describe shows that: id=>primary key with auto_increment.

Comment: I meant what does the migration file in the `yourapp/migrations/` directory look like.

Comment: @Alasdair it shows the creation of the RoadWayData model. The id was created as `('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),` The other fields are initialized the same way as in the class code snippet up above.

Comment: If you can, try an "Insert into ..." statement in a MySQL console and see if it auto increments the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *incident_object* field in the *RoadWayData* model, has the reference *id* (the second parameter) set to its own id. So, when model assigns *incident_object* , it overwrites the *id* of the model.

To fix it, create a new *PostiveIntegerField* (like *incident_id*) and replace

```
incident_object = GenericForeignKey('incident_type', 'id')
```

with

```
incident_id = models.PostiveIntegerField(null=True)
incident_object = GenericForeignKey('incident_type', 'incident_id')
```